# a curious entity framework dilemma

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

When I try and save the record in an Edit view using MVC3 I am getting strange behavior.
Creating a record is fine, nothing unusual there. If I open the same record in the Edit view and make a change to a textbox, then I click save and the record does not get updated. It can see with a breakpoint that the ModelState is not getting set to valid. While in that breakpoint I looked at the Key/Value pairs in the model and I am seeing two keys that seem like they should not be there. 
Here is my model:

```
public class Cases
{
    //case data model for call center
    //implement lists for all related child tables too

    [Key]
    public int CasesID { get; set; }

    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer is Required")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }  //get user name from the aspnet membership

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Case Category is Required")]
    public int CaseCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Technician is Required")]
    public int TechnicianID { get; set; }
    public Technician Technicians { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engine Model is Required")]
    public int EngineModelID { get; set; }
    public EngineModel EngineModel { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string BMSWorkorder { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is Required")]
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string OpenedBy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Opened Date is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? OpenedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClosedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Caller First Name is Required")]
    public string CallerFirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Caller Last Name is Required")]
    public string CallerLastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Qualified is Required")]
    public string Qualified { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ESN is Required")]
    public string ESN { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mileage is Required")]
    public string Mileage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateInService { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ESTR { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EDS is Required")]
    public string EDS { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetSerialNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetModelNumber { get; set; }

    //child Case Notes records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseNotes> CaseNotes { get; set; }

    //child case attachment records
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    //child case complaint records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseComplaint> CaseComplaint { get; set; }

    //tracking fields
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The problem appears to be in the Technicians nav property. The fields in the Technicians nav property are showing up in my model state as a key value pair. If any of them are empty like they could be at any time, they show up as empty key value pairs and cause the model state to not be valid.

Here is the Technician model:

```
public class Technician
{
    public int TechnicianID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string PromoID { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; } //i dont think we need a nav property at this point 06-17-2012

    public string AdditionalContact { get; set; }
}
```

I dont understand what is happening here. Why would those properties be preventing my modelstate from being valid?

Here is my Edit controller action to open the edit view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Cases cases = db.Cases.Find(id);
    db.Entry(cases).Reference(x => x.Customer).Load();
    db.Entry(cases).Collection(x => x.CaseComplaint).Load();
    db.Entry(cases).Collection(x => x.CaseNotes).Load();
    db.Entry(cases).Reference(x => x.Technicians).Load();

    GetCaseCategoryLookup(cases.CaseCategoryID);
    GetEngineModelLookup(cases.EngineModelID);
    GetTechnicianLookup(cases.TechnicianID);
    GetQualifiedList(cases.Qualified);
    GetCaseStatusList(cases.CaseStatus);

    return View(cases);
}
```

Here is my Edit controller action getting the model to update the database. This is where the modelstate is not valid.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Cases cases)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AppHelpers help = new AppHelpers();

        if (cases.CaseStatus == "CLOSED")
        {
            cases.ClosedBy = "USER";
            cases.ClosedDate = help.GetEasternTime();
        }

        cases.ModifiedBy = "USER";
        cases.ModifiedOn = help.GetEasternTime();

        db.Cases.Add(cases);
        db.Entry(cases).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    GetCaseCategoryLookup(cases.CaseCategoryID);
    GetEngineModelLookup(cases.EngineModelID);
    GetTechnicianLookup(cases.TechnicianID);
    GetQualifiedList(cases.Qualified);
    GetCaseStatusList(cases.CaseStatus);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Ryan

Comment: Can you post the model for Technician?

Comment: @Erica I have added the technician model.

Comment: Does it mean that you have a `Technican` instance which has for example empty `FirstName`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Well, All of the technician data in my test database does in fact have complete data for the technician model.

Comment: I added my controller edit methods too

Comment: Still a little confused - the FirstName and LastName are required, so which fields may be empty?

Comment: I am confused too :)
Even though the data in the models are there, the modelstate is showing some of the required data empty...
In particular the modelstate keys of Technician.FirstName and Technician.LastName

Comment: @Ryan just to clarify, you are saying the technician *is* required, as are first and last names. You are also saying that when you submit a form, with a technician selected/populated, the technician model (the object instance) is populated with the correct values. But you have properties on the technician model that are invalid in the modelstate, even though they are populated?

Comment: @MisterJames - The TechnicianID is required in the Case model. TechnicianID is the only property from the Technician model that gets selected in the Case Edit view. When the data on the view gets submitted to the Edit controller action, the model state shows Technician.FirstName, and Technician.LastName as a key/value pair even though they are used on the view. The model state shows those key/values as being null and therefore having an error. What is strange is that if you look at the record for the TechnicianID all of the fields have values.

Comment: Can you add the relevant view code? Actually, I guess what I'm wondering if there is any difference between your create/edit views.  Are you using a partial for the form?